# Spring Boot integration process all aggregated message before shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I would like to process messages in chunks of 10. Also, if there is any message left because of the release strategy should be processed before the Spring boot application shuts down. Below is my simple application, last few messages are not getting processed because it is stuck in the group message.

I am using Spring boot 3.0.6, Spring 6.0.8, and Spring integration 6.0.5. Could you please check if there is anything wrong with the aggregator configuration and how to achieve my desired results i.e. processing all the messages before shutdown?

**Configuration**

```
package com.debopam.springintegrationagg.configuration;

import com.debopam.springintegrationagg.processor.MessageProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MessageCountReleaseStrategy;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SpringAggDemoConfiguration {
    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "requestChannel")
    public interface Gateway {
        Future<Void> sendReceive(String in);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProcessor messageProcessor() {
        return new MessageProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(MessageProcessor messageProcessor) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("requestChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("orgin", Instant.now()))
                .aggregate(a -> a.correlationStrategy(message -> "foo")
                                .releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(10))
                                .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        //.groupTimeout(10000)
                        //.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                )
                .handle(messageProcessor, "process")
                .get();
    }
}
```

**Message Processor Class**

```
package com.debopam.springintegrationagg.processor;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class MessageProcessor {
    public void process(Message<List<String>> messages) {
        //System.out.println("Message header Received :"+message.getHeaders().get("orgin"));
        //List<String> returnMessages = new ArrayList<>(messages.getPayload().size());
        int i = 0;
        log.info("Processing : {}", messages);
        for (String message : messages.getPayload()) {
            i++;
            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Spring Boot Parent run method**

```
package com.debopam.springintegrationagg;

import com.debopam.springintegrationagg.configuration.SpringAggDemoConfiguration;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SpringintegrationaggApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(SpringintegrationaggApplication.class, args);
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringintegrationaggApplication.class, args);
        SpringAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway gateway = ctx.getBean(SpringAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 159; i++) {
            String message = "test item " + count.getAndIncrement();
            log.info("Send - {}", message);
            gateway.sendReceive(message);

        }

        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

**Logs** (Last 7 message is not getting processed)

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=54984:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.0.6/spring-boot-starter-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.6/spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.8/spring-context-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.8/spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.8/spring-expression-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.0.6/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.0.6/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.7/logback-classic-1.4.7.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.7/logback-core-1.4.7.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.19.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.19.0/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.7/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.8/spring-core-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.8/spring-jcl-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-integration/3.0.6/spring-boot-starter-integration-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/3.0.6/spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.8/spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.19/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/6.0.5/spring-integration-core-6.0.5.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/6.0.8/spring-messaging-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.8/spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/2.0.1/spring-retry-2.0.1.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.5.5/reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.4/reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.10.6/micrometer-observation-1.10.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.6/micrometer-commons-1.10.6.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/Users/Debopam/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.26/lombok-1.18.26.jar com.debopam.springintegrationagg.SpringintegrationaggApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2023-06-13T14:33:14.911-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Starting SpringintegrationaggApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 13750 (/Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes started by Debopam in /Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg)
2023-06-13T14:33:14.914-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-13T14:33:15.226-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2023-06-13T14:33:15.239-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2023-06-13T14:33:15.638-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {header-enricher} as a subscriber to the 'requestChannel' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.requestChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {aggregator} as a subscriber to the 'flow.channel#0' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.flow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator} as a subscriber to the 'flow.channel#1' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.flow.channel#1' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.639-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.640-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : started bean 'springAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway#sendReceive(String)'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.640-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] .s.i.g.AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean : started bean 'springAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway'; defined in: 'file [/Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes/com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration$Gateway.class]'; from source: 'file [/Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes/com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration$Gateway.class]'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.653-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Started SpringintegrationaggApplication in 1.021 seconds (process running for 1.284)
2023-06-13T14:33:15.655-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 1
2023-06-13T14:33:15.659-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 2
2023-06-13T14:33:15.659-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 3
2023-06-13T14:33:15.659-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 4
2023-06-13T14:33:15.659-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 5
2023-06-13T14:33:15.660-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 6
2023-06-13T14:33:15.660-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 7
2023-06-13T14:33:15.660-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 8
2023-06-13T14:33:15.660-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 9
2023-06-13T14:33:15.660-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 10
2023-06-13T14:33:15.661-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 11
2023-06-13T14:33:15.661-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 12
2023-06-13T14:33:15.661-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 13
2023-06-13T14:33:15.661-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 14
2023-06-13T14:33:15.661-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 15
2023-06-13T14:33:15.662-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 16
2023-06-13T14:33:15.662-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 17
2023-06-13T14:33:15.662-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 18
2023-06-13T14:33:15.663-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 19
2023-06-13T14:33:15.663-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 20
2023-06-13T14:33:15.663-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 21
2023-06-13T14:33:15.664-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 22
2023-06-13T14:33:15.664-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 23
2023-06-13T14:33:15.665-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 24
2023-06-13T14:33:15.665-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 25
2023-06-13T14:33:15.666-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 26
2023-06-13T14:33:15.666-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 27
2023-06-13T14:33:15.666-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 28
2023-06-13T14:33:15.666-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 29
2023-06-13T14:33:15.667-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 30
2023-06-13T14:33:15.667-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 31
2023-06-13T14:33:15.667-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 32
2023-06-13T14:33:15.667-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 33
2023-06-13T14:33:15.667-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 34
2023-06-13T14:33:15.668-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 35
2023-06-13T14:33:15.668-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 36
2023-06-13T14:33:15.668-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 37
2023-06-13T14:33:15.668-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 38
2023-06-13T14:33:15.668-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 39
2023-06-13T14:33:15.669-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 40
2023-06-13T14:33:15.669-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 41
2023-06-13T14:33:15.669-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 42
2023-06-13T14:33:15.669-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 43
2023-06-13T14:33:15.670-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 44
2023-06-13T14:33:15.670-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 45
2023-06-13T14:33:15.670-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 46
2023-06-13T14:33:15.670-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [TaskExecutor-13] c.d.s.processor.MessageProcessor         : Processing : GenericMessage [payload=[test item 3, test item 28, test item 1, test item 8, test item 2, test item 17, test item 20, test item 29, test item 19, test item 13], headers={orgin=2023-06-13T21:33:15.460086Z, id=b62caadd-a5e2-77cf-dfd8-7f04550e7bef, timestamp=1686691995668}]
2023-06-13T14:33:15.670-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] c.d.s.SpringintegrationaggApplication    : Send - test item 47
2023-06-13T14:33:15.672-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [TaskExecutor-15] c.d.s.processor.MessageProcessor         : Processing : GenericMessage [payload=[test item 10, test item 9, test item 12, test item 14, test item 23, test item 5, test item 7, test item 21, test item 6, test item 15], headers={orgin=2023-06-13T21:33:15.460086Z, id=77037eaf-67fa-1292-dd35-c2cbf5a58fdc, timestamp=1686691995672}]
2023-06-13T14:33:15.672-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [TaskExecutor-30] c.d.s.processor.MessageProcessor         : Processing : GenericMessage [payload=[test item 24, test item 16, test item 18, test item 11, test item 4, test item 22, test item 25, test item 26, test item 27, test item 30], headers={orgin=2023-06-13T21:33:15.460086Z, id=598a19a9-e8c0-8499-0e93-ffa26909ec92, timestamp=1686691995672}]
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {header-enricher} as a subscriber to the 'requestChannel' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.requestChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {aggregator} as a subscriber to the 'flow.channel#0' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.flow.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [TaskExecutor-40] c.d.s.processor.MessageProcessor         : Processing : GenericMessage [payload=[test item 31, test item 32, test item 33, test item 34, test item 35, test item 36, test item 37, test item 38, test item 39, test item 40], headers={orgin=2023-06-13T21:33:15.460086Z, id=aacfde22-2f7c-6403-9113-cc5e79e0221d, timestamp=1686691995673}]
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.673-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {service-activator} as a subscriber to the 'flow.channel#1' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.674-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.flow.channel#1' has 0 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.674-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method flow'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.675-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : stopped bean 'springAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway#sendReceive(String)'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.675-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] .s.i.g.AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean : stopped bean 'springAggDemoConfiguration.Gateway'; defined in: 'file [/Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes/com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration$Gateway.class]'; from source: 'file [/Users/Debopam/Documents/Workspace/springintegrationagg/target/classes/com/debopam/springintegrationagg/configuration/SpringAggDemoConfiguration$Gateway.class]'
2023-06-13T14:33:15.675-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2023-06-13T14:33:15.675-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2023-06-13T14:33:15.675-07:00  INFO 13750 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: With your `releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(10))` and without `groupTimeout()`, those messages which cannot form a group of 10, won't never be released independently of the shutdown or not. See if `MessageGroupStoreReaper` with its `expireOnDestroy = true` can help you somehow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#reaper

Comment: Another way to try to achieve a graceful shutdown is to add a `spring-integration-jmx` dependency. It will add a an `Orderly Shutdown` feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#jmx-shutdown